# Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib in matlab

Tags: matlab

macos high sierra 10.13.1 xcode 9.2 matlab 2017b

while running a program in mac matlab in 2017b version, I tried to run pmtk3 from this [link](https://github.com/probml/pmtk3) and while running I got the following error while running second command

1. Steps:

   1. run initPmtk3.m (takes a few minutes)
   2. run testPmtk3.m (takes under a minute)
   3. run runDemos.m (takes about 1 hour)

error:

```
'/Users/laxmikadariya/Documents/MATLAB/pmtk3-master/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc/lbfgsC.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/laxmikadariya/Documents/MATLAB/pmtk3-master/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc/lbfgsC.mexmaci64,
6): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib
  Referenced from:
  /Users/laxmikadariya/Documents/MATLAB/pmtk3-master/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc/lbfgsC.mexmaci64
    Reason: image not found.
```

How can I solve this issue in matlab mac?

I tried to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in .bash_profile as 
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/sys/os/maci64'

this couldnot solve the problem

Comment: Did you run `mex -setup` in MATLAB before `initPmtk3`? It compiles a MEX-file, you need to have your `mex` command configured first. Note also that in newer MacOS, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` no longer works as it did before.

Comment: @Cris  is there any link , that guides for mex  -setup. where does this loader_path reference to???

Comment: @cris Luengo  I have x code 9.2 and mex setup shows 'Xcode with Clang'. how do I reference to library path in newer macos??

Comment: When compiling "properly" on MacOS, the mex-file will have the absolute or relative paths to used shared libraries included in it, there should be no need to manually set the path. `@loader_path` is the path of the mex-file in this case. This is strange, usually mex-files link to `@rpath/libmex.dylib`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo is this related to compiler decrepency? or why such error is produced??

Comment: Let me try out this package tonight on my Mac, it's hard to understand why this goes wrong without hands-on interaction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lbfgsC.mexmaci64` file comes pre-compiled, and with a time-stamp from 2012. Many things have changed on MacOS since then... :)

In a terminal window, I tried:

```
$> otool -L lbfgsC.mexmaci64
lbfgsC.mexmaci64:
    @loader_path/libmx.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/libmex.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @loader_path/libmat.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
```

As you can see, it references MATLAB's libraries using `@loader_path`, which is wrong. That should be `@rpath`.

I tried recompiling the MEX-file, from the MATLAB command prompt:

```
>> cd pmtk3/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc
>> mex -compatibleArrayDims lbfgsC.c
```

The `-compatibleArrayDims` option is necessary because the code is very old, and uses `int` for array sizes (32 bits), rather than `mwSize` (64 bits).

In a terminal window I now see:

```
$> otool -L lbfgsC.mexmaci64
lbfgsC.mexmaci64:
    @rpath/libmx.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
```

This looks a lot better, it's using `@rpath` as it should. The MEX-file now ran, meaning that the linker problem is solved.

There is another MEX-file in this same directory, it will have the same problem. You'll have to compile that one at the same time:

```
>> mex -compatibleArrayDims mcholC.c
```

Comment: Failing for me:  `mex -compatibleArrayDims lbfgsC.c
mex: unrecognized option `-compatibleArrayDims'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=mex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lbfgsC.c
This is MeX  Version 1.05  18 XII 1993  (B. Jackowski & M. Ry\'cko)
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.1 #
     include <math.h>
?`

Comment: @zkurtz: it looks like you are running `pdftex` rather than MATLAB’s `mex` function. You need to run the `mex` command from within MATLAB.

Comment: Say you can't recompile these files. How else could this issue be overcome? Would copying some files to some other place work?

Comment: @gen I don’t know, maybe try copying the `libmex.dylib` file to the directory where the MEX-files are. If that works, maybe some other dylibs need to be copied also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the libraries to your matlab startup script

`/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/.matlab7rc.sh`.

Add

`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/sys/os/maci64"`

Then startup matlab from the command line

`/Applications/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/matlab`

Comment: Sorry, that's a bad idea. You are trying to tell MATLAB where to find its own libraries? If you read my answer above, you'll see that recompiling the MEX-file solved the issue.

Comment: Yeah. New readers: definitely don't do this! In general, don't do anything that requires you to modify any file under your `MATLAB_<version>.app` app bundle (even if MathWorks themselves tell you to).

Answer (score 0):

Having similar issue on MacOS 11.7.4 (also on a different MacOS 13.0.1 but would be happy to get either working).
[image: initial_issue]
A number of solutions [were suggested on a Matlab Answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/763346-mexfile-error-libmex-dylib-not-loaded) but nothing has worked.

I can't tell if this is a permissions issue with compiling mex files in newer MacOS or if I'm missing some key step. Obviously I linked to Xcode via `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` from Terminal and ran `mex -setup` from Matlab.

Since I kept getting errors about not finding libmex.dylib (and libmat.dylib) and those files exist in 'MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v84/bin/maci64' I went ahead and coped those to 'usr/local/lib' and added that folder to path. The system still found a way to bug out (screenshot from different computer but have replicated this on both machines):
[image]

Anyone have any ideas or gotten mex files to compile in Matlab on OS ≥11.0?

**UPDATE:** Disabled SIP and they compiled. People don't recommend this but I never found an alternative. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection