# how to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in macos high Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, matlab, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to use matlab 2917b in mac . while running it shows

```
/Users/laxmikadariya/Documents/MATLAB/pmtk3-master/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc/lbfgsC.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/laxmikadariya/Documents/MATLAB/pmtk3-master/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc/lbfgsC.mexmaci64,
6): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib
  Referenced from:
  /Users/laxmikadariya/Documents/MATLAB/pmtk3-master/pmtksupportCopy/markSchmidt-9march2011/markSchmidt/minFunc/lbfgsC.mexmaci64
    Reason: image not found.
```

it seems that the path of the library is not found. The library is located at 
/Users/laxmikadariya/Desktop/matlab/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64

however setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH  in .bashrc_profile as

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/Users/laxmikadariya/Desktop/matlab/MATLAB_R2017b.app/bin/maci64:/Users/laxmikadariya/Desktop/matlab/MATLAB_R2017b.app/sys/os/maci64':$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

is not working.

how can i set the path in newer mac??

Comment: Please show your code in which you set it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added the bash_profile code

Comment: I set mine in `$HOME/.profile`

Comment: @MarkSetchell no luck in changing ithe path in .profile aswell.

Comment: Did you log out and back in since changing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library not loaded: @loader\_path/libmex.dylib in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458660/library-not-loaded-loader-path-libmex-dylib-in-matlab)

Comment: This is the same question you posted earlier. As I told you, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't reliable any more in MacOS. As a security measure, its value I no longer propagated to child processes. Basically it has become useless. You won't be able to use it to influence the MATLAB process because that is started through a shell script, which runs in a child process.