# Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib in Matlab Version R2018a

Tags: macos, matlab

I tried following the recommendations offered in this link ([Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458660/library-not-loaded-loader-path-libmex-dylib-in-matlab)) but nothing has worked.

> Invalid MEX-file
>   '/Users/Nyax/Desktop/m-files/mice/lib/mice.mexmaci64':
>   dlopen(/Users/Nyax/Desktop/m-files/mice/lib/mice.mexmaci64, 6):
>   Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Nyax/Desktop/m-files/mice/lib/mice.mexmaci64   Reason: image
>   not found.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information to help you. So far all I can say is "sorry it doesn't work". I can see you're on MacOS, but I don't know which version, I don't know which version of MATLAB you have, and, most importantly, I don't know what MEX-file you're trying to load and where you got it from. My best advice with this knowledge: find the source code and recompile it on your machine.

Comment: @CrisLuengo macos high sierra 10.13.4 xcode 9.4.1  matlab 2018a. The MEX-file I am currently trying to load is Mice.c which I got from https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit//MATLAB/MacIntel_OSX_AppleC_MATLAB8.x_64bit/packages/dscriptn.txt

Comment: The [README](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit//MATLAB/MacIntel_OSX_AppleC_MATLAB8.x_64bit/packages/README) file contains information on how to recompile. Did you follow those directions?

Comment: Yes I followed those directions and still experienced the same error. @CrisLuengo is there any other way around this problem?