# Invalid glmnet Mex file in matlab

Tags: macos, matlab, mex, glmnet

I am running [glmnet](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/glmnet-matlab/) package on MATLAB 2019a in macOS 10.14.5. I have also installed Xcode in my laptop.

I got the error like the following:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/Users/Desktop/Research/Paper Code/glmnet/glmnetMex.mexmaci64' : dlopen(/Users/Desktop/Research/Paper Code/glmnet/glmnetMex.mexmaci64,
6): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Desktop/Research/Paper Code/glmnet/glmnetMex.mexmaci64
```

I have tried the code `mex -setup` and got

```
MEX configured to use 'Xcode with Clang' for C language compilation.
Warning: The MATLAB C and Fortran API has changed to support MATLAB variables with more than 2^32-1 elements. 
In the near future you will be required to update your code to utilize the new API. 
You can find more information about this at:  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
```

I've found some advice from [mathworks](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/answers/244833-unable-to-compile-my-c-files-using-the-mex-command-under-os-x-10-5-and-xcode-7-0) specific to `mex` but I am not sure whether this can solve my problem. I stopped here since I am not sure if I should follow this answer to delete something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make sure, you don't have spaces in your path. eg. "Paper Code"

Comment: Did you build the MEX-file yourself or did it come pre-compiled?

Comment: Spaces in the path are fine; Matlab and the DLL loader handle that correctly, and this problem reproduces on a path without spaces.

Comment: Good question! It's helpful that you included a link to the actual library, your system info, and the exact error message you got. It would be helpful if you would also include the exact code that you ran that produced that error message, too, to make it easier for answerers to reproduce the issue. (I was able to do it easily enough using the example code in Glmnet, but not every problem is going to work that way.)

Comment: @CrisLuengo It is pre-compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glmnetMex` MEX file included with the Glmnet download looks busticated on newer versions of macOS because it was compiled on a much older version of macOS ([OS X 10.8, according to their website](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_matlab/download.html)), and the DLL library loading mechanism has changed since then. (It should be using `@rpath` instead of `@loader_path`.) You will need to rebuild the MEX file yourself, or contact the Glmnet maintainers and ask them to provide a new build.

To rebuild the MEX file:

1. Set up Matlab with `mex -setup` to use a compiler that can compile Fortran MEX files. (I don't actually know how to do this.)
2. In Matlab, `cd` to the `glmnet_matlab` directory, `!rm glmnetMex.mexmaci64`, and then run `mex glmnetMex.F`

I would consider this a bug in the Glmnet distribution; I have reported it upstream to the Glmnet maintainers.

(I can reproduce this issue with a fresh download of Glmnet on my macOS 10.14.6 box running Matlab R2019a, too.)

Here's a similar problem with another Matlab library's pre-built MEX file: [Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458660/library-not-loaded-loader-path-libmex-dylib-in-matlab). Next time try Googling for various parts of your error message; searching for "Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib" will pull up that question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I still got warning after following these two steps. I have edited my question to make it more specific. Maybe that explains more?

Comment: You're welcome! That new error/warning message looks completely unrelated to me. I recommend you post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Janke's answer worked well, except for the second step where I needed to compile using

```
mex FFLAGS='-fdefault-real-8 -ffixed-form -compatibleArrayDims' glmnetMex.F GLMnet.f
```

See also here: https://github.com/growlix/glmnet_matlab

I am running MATLAB 2019a with MacOS 10.15.3.